# missing information in crawling data

Tags: html, r, dom, web-crawler

I want to use R to crawl all the news(title,url and text) related to AlphaGo in XXX , and the page url is `http://www.xxxxxx.com/search/?q=AlphaGo`. Here is my code:

```
url <- "http://www.xxxxxx.com/search/?q=AlphaGo"
info <- debugGatherer()
handle <- getCurlHandle(cookiejar ="",
                        #turn the page
                        followlocation = TRUE,
                        autoreferer = TRUE,
                        debugfunc = info$update,
                        verbose = TRUE,
                        httpheader = list(
                          from = "eddie@r-datacollection.com",
                          'user-agent' = str_c(R.version$version.string,
                                               ",",R.version$platform)
                        ))
html <- getURL(url,curl=handle,header = TRUE)
parsedpage <- htmlParse(html)
```

However, when I use code

```
xpathSApply(parsedpage,"//h3//a",xmlGetAttr,"href")
```

to check if I have found the targeted code, I find that all the content of the information of related news is missing. Then I found that the `DOM elements`(Chrome is what I used) after pressing `F12` contains the information I want, while nothing in `sources`(which is really messy like all the elements are piled up together). So I change my code to :

```
parsed_page <- htmlTreeParse(file = url,asTree = T)
```

with hope to acquire the dom tree instead. 
Still, this time the information is missing, what I find is all the missing information is the information folded in the `DOM elements`(I have never met this situation before).

Any idea how the problem happen and how I could fix this?

Comment: What is the output you want? A list of url or the text from each page?

Comment: Both of them, something wrong with my code?

Comment: You're violating item 3 in the CNN ToC. Please make sure you inform others you're asking them to help you in unethical behaviour that could land them fines or jail time.

Comment: Dear @hrbrmstr , thanks for your advice and I would remove the related information but leaving the general problem itself. Also it’s purely for academic and personal use, but I totally understand your concern. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the thoughts @Colin provided, I tried to follow along the original code. So I code as follows for the dynamic content in JSON file with package `RJSONIO`

```
url <- "https://search.xxxxxx.io/content?q=AlphaGo"
content <- fromJSON(url)
content1 <- content$result
content_result <- matrix(NA,10,5)
for(i in 1:length(content1)){
  content_result[i,] <- c("CNN", content1[[i]]$firstPublishDate,ifelse(class(content1[[i]]$headline) != "NULL",content1[[i]]$headline,"NA"),
                         content1[[i]]$body,content1[[i]]$url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not come from your code. The results page is dynamically generated, thus the links and texts are not available in plain html in the result page (as you can see if you look at the source code).

There is only 10 results, so I suggest you manually create a list of url.

I don't know the package you used in this code. But I suggest you go for `rvest`, which seems way simpler than the package you used.

For :

```
url <- "http://money.cnn.com/2017/05/25/technology/alphago-china-ai/index.html"

library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="storytext"]/p') %>% 
  html_text()

 [1] " A computer system that Google engineers trained to play the game Go beat the world's best human player Thursday in China. The victory was AlphaGo's second this week over Chinese professional Ke Jie, clinching the best-of-three series at the Future of Go Summit in Wuzhen.  "                                  
 [2] " Afterward, Google engineers said AlphaGo estimated that the first 50 moves -- by both players -- were virtually perfect. And the first 100 moves were the best anyone had ever played against AlphaGo's master version. "                                                                                           
 [3] " Related: Google's man-versus-machine showdown is blocked in China "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [4] " \"What an amazing and complex game! Ke Jie pushed AlphaGo right to the limit,\" said DeepMind CEO Demis Hassabis on Twitter. DeepMind is a British artificial intelligence company that developed AlphaGo and was purchased by Google in 2014. "                                                                    
 [5] " DeepMind made a stir in January 2016 when it first announced it had used artificial intelligence to master Go, a 2,500-year-old game. Computer scientists had struggled for years to get computers to excel at the game. "                                                                                          
 [6] " In Go, two players alternate placing white and black stones on a grid. The goal is to claim the most territory. To do so, you surround your opponent's pieces so that they're removed from the board. "                                                                                                             
 [7] " The board's 19-by-19 grid is so vast that it allows a near infinite combination of moves, making it tough for machines to comprehend. Games such as chess have come quicker to machines. "                                                                                                                          
 [8] " Related: Elon Musk's new plan to save humanity from AI "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [9] " The Google engineers at DeepMind rely on deep learning, a trendy form of artificial intelligence that's driving remarkable gains in what computers are capable of. World-changing technologies that loom on the horizon, such as autonomous vehicles, rely on deep learning to effectively see and drive on roads. "
[10] " AlphaGo's achievement is also a reminder of the steady improvement of machines' ability to complete tasks once reserved for humans. As machines get smarter, there are concerns about how society will be disrupted, and if all humans will be able to find work. "                                                 
[11] " Historically, mankind's development of tools has always created new jobs that never existed before. But the gains in artificial intelligence are coming at a breakneck pace, which will likely accentuate upheaval in the short term. "                                                                             
[12] " Related: Google uses AI to help diagnose breast cancer "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[13] " The 19-year-old Ke and AlphaGo will play a third match Saturday morning. The summit will also feature a match Friday in which five human players will team up against AlphaGo. "
```

Best

Colin

Comment: I thought about your method carefully, seems like it would be a huge project if starting the work from the page I provided, even with `rvest`, as what you did here is just parse the html file of each news page, which would be definitely simple. What if we need to crawl the url, instead of producing the url ourselves?